# xsl:copy-of. Retain original parent node?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I've seen plenty of `xsl:copy-of` examples, such as this one, where the encompassing parent node is hard coded. ie `<output>` but is there a way to use `xsl:copy-of` & retain the parent node? `<library>` in this instance.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<library>
    <category name="dogs">
        <book>
            <name>All about dogs</name>
            <author>Someone</author>
        </book>
    </category>
     <category name="cats">
        <book>
            <name>All about cats</name>
            <author>Someone</author>
        </book>
    </category>
</library>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <xsl:copy-of select="library/category[@name='cats']" />
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <output>
        <category name="cats">
            <book>
                <name>All about cats</name>
                <author>Someone</author>
            </book>
        </category>
    </output>
```

Comment: In XSLT 3 you could use `<xsl:copy-of select="snapshot(library/category[@name='cats'])/.."/>`.

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

No, `xsl:copy-of` performs a deep copy of the selected node(s). If you want to emit the parent of the node, then you will need to process the content differently.

One way would be to apply-templates and have one template that matches elements that have cats, use `xsl:copy` for the `library` element and then `xsl:copy-of` selecting the `category` with cats, and a more generic template to match other nodes that simply continues processing and does not generate any content:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="*[category[@name='cats']]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="category[@name='cats']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```